# Linux AWS immediately down by rm -rf /*

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I was working to delete a single file.

I accidentally typed `/*` and all files are gone. It's okay since I have my backups but the main problem is that I'm not able to login into `aws ec2 instance`. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You need to delete your instance and create a new one. Your instance is empty now.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to login into the instance because you tore it down with that command. You should login to the EC2 dashboard (or use the aws-console) and terminate the instance and / or start a new one from the image backup you may have.

Comment: if i dont have the image backup then?

Comment: You will have to create a new instance of the same OS version and redo the setup that you may have done for the original instance. Then you can restore the required files and hopefully you would have an almost duplicate instance. And always take image backups!